# UISegmentedControl click not fire when click

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I encountered a problem: VC contains UISegmentedControl, I used NavigationController Push this VC. When UISegmentedControl is clicked, the Click event is not fired.

```
let items = ["Photos", "Map"]

lazy var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
     let SC = UISegmentedControl( items: items)

     //- size of this segmentedControl:
     SC.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
     SC.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     SC.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
     SC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapSegmentedControl), for: .valueChanged)
     return SC

}()

let VC1:Photos
let VC2:PlaceMap

init(){
     self.VC1 = Photos()
     self.VC2 = PlaceMap()

     super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
     fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     view.backgroundColor = .white

     setUpViews()
     setUpSegmentedControl()
}

func setUpSegmentedControl(){
     addChild(VC1)
     addChild(VC2)

     self.view.addSubview(VC1.view)
     self.view.addSubview(VC2.view)

     VC1.didMove(toParent:self )
     VC2.didMove(toParent:self )

     VC1.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 90, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
     VC2.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 90, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)

     VC2.view.isHidden = true
}

@objc func didTapSegmentedControl(){
     VC1.view.isHidden = true
     VC2.view.isHidden = true

     if ( segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ) {
         self.VC1.view.isHidden = false
     } else {
         // show VC2 : Map
         self.VC2.view.isHidden = false
     }
}

-- add segmentedControl
func setUpViews(){
        
        view.addSubview(imgBackwardArrow)
        view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
            imgBackwardArrow.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,constant: 2),
            imgBackwardArrow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,constant: 12),
            imgBackwardArrow.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:35),
            imgBackwardArrow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:35),
            //
            //segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,constant: 2),
            segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,constant: 60),
             segmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        ])
        
        //- hook
        let singleTapClose = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(didTapBackwardArrowBtn))
        imgBackwardArrow.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imgBackwardArrow.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapClose)
    }
```

Comment: Where's the code that adds `segmentedControl` to the view?

Comment: @HangerRash, I just updated the programmatical approach adding the segmented control. Thanks

Comment: One thing you should definitely try is to use proper constraints for all views you add. Set the segmented control's topAnchor to be relative to the backward arrow's bottomAnchor. Then setup the two view controller views so their top anchors are relative to the bottomAnchor of the segmented control. It's possible the two view controller views are on top of the segmented control which prevent any taps on it from working.

Comment: @HangarRash, let say I did everything correct for UISegmentedControl. I can use it when I just present(VC). However, when I push to show using NavigationController, I cannot click the UISegmentedControl as described above. Do you know why this happens?